# Python matplotlib, invalid shape for image data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pytorch

Currently I have this code to show three images:

```
imshow(image1, title='1')
imshow(image2, title='2')
imshow(image3, title='3')
```

And it works fine. But I am trying to put them all three in a row instead of column.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
f = plt.figure()
f.add_subplot(1,3,1)
plt.imshow(image1)
f.add_subplot(1,3,2)
plt.imshow(image2)
f.add_subplot(1,3,3)
plt.imshow(image3)
```

It throws

> TypeError: can't convert CUDA tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.

If I do

```
f = plt.figure()
f.add_subplot(1,3,1)
plt.imshow(image1.cpu())
f.add_subplot(1,3,2)
plt.imshow(image2.cpu())
f.add_subplot(1,3,3)
plt.imshow(image3.cpu())
```

It throws

> TypeError: Invalid shape (1, 3, 128, 128) for image data

How should I fix this or is there an easier way to implement it?

Comment: Use Matplotlib's [`subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html#matplotlib-pyplot-subplots) function, specifying the number of rows you want through the `ncols` argument.

Comment: @Lith I have tried with this code:

    `fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)
    axs[0].imshow(image1.cpu())
    axs[1].imshow(image2.cpu())
    axs[2].imshow(image3.cpu())`

and still getting `TypeError: Invalid shape (1, 3, 128, 128) for image data`

Comment: I don't know about Pytorch, but it seems that the `cpu()` method is transforming the array `image` with (I suppose) dimensions (128,128)  into another of dimensions (1,3,128,128), which is invalid for the `imshow` function. The argument of this function must be a two dimensional array (or 3-dimensional if you are working with RGB data), representing the data values of the pixels of the image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The matplotlib function 'imshow' gets 3-channel pictures as (h, w, 3) as you can see in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).

It seems that you passed a "batch" of single image (the first dimention) of three channels (second dimention) of the image (h and w are the third and forth dimention).

You need to reshape or view your image (after converting to cpu, try to use:

```
image1.squeeze().permute(1,2,0)
```

The result will be an image of the desired shape (128, 128, 3).

The squeeze() function will remove the first dimention. And the premute() function will transpose the dimenstion where the first will shift to the third position and the two other will shift to the beginning.

Also, have a look here for further talk on the GPU and CPU issues:
[link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cant-convert-cuda-tensor-to-numpy-use-tensor-cpu-to-copy-the-tensor-to-host-memory-first/38301/8)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you that helped!