# 'Invalid shape (28, 28, 1) for image data'

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is example of my code:

```
    (train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.mnist.load_data()
    
    train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1))
    test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1))
    
    #train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0
    train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255
    
    test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255
    
    plt.imshow(train_images[0])
```

But I'm getting [Invalid shape (28, 28, 1) for image data error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oW8z.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post images of data/code/error messages. Post the text here on SO instead. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to attract good answers. I suggest you edit your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python matplotlib, invalid shape for image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480762/python-matplotlib-invalid-shape-for-image-data)

Answer (score 0):

Do plt.imshow(train_images[0][0]) before / 255

OR do train_images = train_images[0] / 255 and keep your code as is

You can figure it out if you print train_images[0].shape it says 60000 x 28 x 28

edit: added code

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models
(train_images, train_labels) = datasets.mnist.load_data()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
train_images = train_images[0] / 255
plt.imshow(train_images[0])
```